# Can we read character by character in PHP without using any builtin function...?

Tags: php, string, loops, char

I want to write the algorithm for reading character by character from string in PHP. Is it possible to do this without using any builtin function...? If not possible, then can we do this by using minimum function (i.e count/size)....?

Comment: If a built in function can do it, so can you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string in PHP is in fact an array and can be addressed as such

```
$str = 'Hello World';

echo $str[0];  // H
echo $str[1];  // e
```

Comment: Thank you.
So we can loop through the whole string like we do in case of array. In this way, a generic algorithm is developed.

Comment: Thank you very much folly. I am thankful of your support and help. Stay Blessed!

Answer (score 2):

yes for example the string is "Hello world" then here is the code to access it

```
<?php
    $var = "Hello World!!" ;
    for($count = 0 ; $count < strlen($var) ; $count ++)
    {
        echo $var[$count] ;
    }
?>
```

The above code traverses the string linearly till the value of counter is less than the string length owing to the fact that the counter was initialised to 0, Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much. I am thankful of you for your support and help.

Comment: @RiggsFolly dude this question popped up in my "Questions" list at that very moment and seriously what do you want that your answer is superior over mine, ok off you go, i was just trying to help someone just as people helped me.